# Permanently changing column name in JSON SNOWFLAKE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
2   {    "country": "England",    "id": "100200",    "status": "morestatus"  }
3   {    "country": "Netherlands",    "id": "100300",    "status": "morestatus"  }
1   {    "country": "UK",    "id": "100100",    "status": "somestatus"  }
```

how to change the country to COUNTRY permanently with update command:

```
SET T.RECORD = object_delete(object_insert(RECORD, 'COUNTRY', RECORD:country), 'country') 
WHERE T.RECORD:country
```

Comment: Can you add more context please? I edited the question for formatting

Comment: UPDATE "KAFKA_DB"."KAFKA_SCHEMA"."TARGET" T
SET T.RECORD = object_delete(object_insert(T.RECORD,'COUNTRY',T.RECORD:country),'country') 
WHERE T.RECORD:country

Comment: SQL compilation error: Invalid data type [VARIANT] for predicate [GET(T.RECORD, 'country')]

Comment: executed above SQL getting the error above. What could be wrong in the where clause. Even added single as well as once double code for the small (country)

Answer (score 1):

You can nest object_insert inside object_delete to do this.

```
create or replace temp table t1 as select parse_json('{ "country": "England", "id": "100200", "status": "morestatus" }') as V;

insert into t1 select parse_json('{ "country": "Netherlands", "id": "100300", "status": "morestatus" }');
insert into t1 select parse_json('{ "country": "UK",    "id": "100100",    "status": "somestatus"  }');


update t1 set v = object_delete(object_insert(v, 'COUNTRY', v:country), 'country');
```